# Text floats even when fixed relative to top on Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

In the template we have assume 8 rows are there. And among last 4 rows, last one only eligible to be displayed others will be failed in the "print when" expression.

Settings of each row:

Position Type: Fixed to Top

Stretch Type: No Stretch

Horizontal Alignment: Left

Veritical Alignment: Top

Having all these settings, the last row is getting displayed on its position only and there is a blank three rows above.

Can you please help in resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you post your jrxml? Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3JCDGIhqVg6ZVhnV3pqbVBqSmM

Comment: Can you please check the above link for the same?

Comment: Closing for lack of *minimal* working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Keep the position type as Float, that should help.

Comment: Have you selected print blank when null option for the blank row text fields ?

Comment: Remove line when blank option is set. As per this setting, it should not be displayed...